# jQuery code revealer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I've seen a jquery plugin that was able to "expand" horizontally a `<pre>` element when you moved your mouse over it.

But I don't remember it's name or where to find it...

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it without a plugin.

**[See the following on jsFiddle →](http://jsfiddle.net/jclem/N2xL7/)**

I also like to set `overflow-x` on the expanded pre so that one can still scroll to see lines that are wider than the expanded size. I don't like scroll bars on the narrower ones, so I set `overflow` to hidden in the CSS and on `mouseleave`.

```
$(function() {
    $('pre').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            width: 400
        }, function() {
            $(this).css('overflow-x','auto');
        });
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            width: 200
        }, function() {
            $(this).css('overflow','hidden');
        });
    });
});
```

Assuming the CSS is as follows:

```
pre {
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Or even better! Use a `figure` and `figcaption` element to provide a handy tip for each code listing as seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jclem/N2xL7/2/).

On top of that, you could use a jQuery plugin like [ScrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) to ensure that the code scrolls back to the left whenever the mouse leaves it.

Comment: The effect is a bit silly when your code doesn't actually overflow the element.  I like to add a test before proceeding with the bubble-out animation.  You can check for overflow by testing if elt.scrollWidth > elt.clientWidth  where elt is $(this).get(0) in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a plugin for this. You can do this using the [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function.

```
$('div').bind({
    mouseover: function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            width: 300
        })
    },
    mouseout: function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            width: 100
        })
    }
})
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/zgTw3/2/

Answer (score 1):

are you looking for this www.sohtanaka.com ?

Comment: i did that but the js is eval'd :(

Comment: append a class name resizeMe with the element you want to resize on mouse hover, then on mouse hover $(this).animate({width:screen.width},200);